# Why is `http` in http-enumerator an Iteratee?

Tags: haskell, loops

The type signature for [`http`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-enumerator/0.7.1/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Enumerator.html#v%3ahttp) is:

```hs
http :: MonadIO m
     => Request m
     -> (W.Status -> W.ResponseHeaders -> Iteratee S.ByteString m a)
     -> Manager
     -> Iteratee S.ByteString m a
```

Why isn't it this instead?

```hs
http :: MonadIO m => … -> m a
```

If I understand correctly, an [`Iteratee x m a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/enumerator/0.4.14/doc/html/Data-Enumerator.html#t%3aIteratee) is like a monadic parser that consumes a stream of items of type `x`.  It makes sense for `http`'s callback to be an `Iteratee`, as it consumes the response body.

However, `http` itself does not appear to consume any input.  The [httpLbs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-enumerator/0.7.1/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Enumerator.html#v%3ahttpLbs) function executes `http` with [`run_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/enumerator/0.4.14/doc/html/Data-Enumerator.html#v%3arun_) (defined in Data.Enumerator).  From what I can tell, `run` considers it an error if the iteratee given to it expects input:

```hs
-- | Run an iteratee until it finishes, and return either the final value
-- (if it succeeded) or the error (if it failed).
run :: Monad m => Iteratee a m b
    -> m (Either Exc.SomeException b)
run i = do
    mStep <- runIteratee $ enumEOF ==<< i
    case mStep of
        Error err -> return $ Left err
        Yield x _ -> return $ Right x
        Continue _ -> error "run: divergent iteratee"
```

So if `http` does not consume input, why is it an iteratee?  Why isn't it just a `MonadIO` action?

Comment: How does `http` not consume data from a TCP connection?

Comment: The arguments you have omitted using `...` are important.  One is a function that returns an Iteratee.

Comment: @luqui: I edited the post to include the full signature of `http`, and to clarify that its callback argument consumes input (from what I can tell).  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's not an error to pass `run` (or `run_`) an `Iteratee` that expects input; that's why we first pass in `enumEOF`. It's invalid for an `Iteratee` to continue expecting input after receiving an EOF.
2. By leaving the result of `http` in the `Iteratee` monad, you can perform multiple actions in the same pipeline, such as streaming two HTTP responses into a file.